# How to transform test data according to model in CNN?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm new to Keras and I am learning to build Convolutional Neural Network models. I am using MNIST dataset.

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

After building and evaluating I am getting 99%+ accuracy.

```
model = NN_model() # Sequential model built with multiple Convolution and pooling layers

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3, batch_size=200, verbose=2)

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

Now, I want to check result manually by picking a random image, printing it using matplotlib and then predicting it using the learned model. For example, the X_test[39] data looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/r2sz1iXd).

```
print(model.predict(X_test[39],verbose=2))
```

When I try to do this, it asks me to convert the pre-processed data into conv2d data,  as the model is converting it. How do I apply this transformation on test data manually?

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 28, 28)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model is not converting anything, the network takes a batch of images which has shape `(num_samples, channels, width, height)`. In this case you have a single sample so you should set `num_samples` to one by adding a new dimension:

```
sample = X_test[39]
model.predict(sample[np.newaxis, :, :, :])
```

Or you can also just reshape the sample array to `(1, 1, 28, 28)`.

Comment: Standard Keras uses `channels_last` (unless the user has explicitly changed it), meaning the shape should be `(1,28,28,1)`.

Comment: @Daniel Read the error message in the question, it is already (1, 1, 28, 28).

Comment: @Daniel Its (1,28,28) after discarding the first dimension (X_test[39]).

Comment: @Daniel Precisely, the input was given as (1,28, 28). The full input was (something, 1, 28, 28).

Comment: @Daniel Please read the question again before commenting. The first dimension is being discarded as X_test[39] is being given as input (not the full X_test).

Comment: Hmm... sorry.... in that case, they need to take a slice: `X_test[39:40]`. But just in case they haven't changed the standard data format, my first comment will be kept. (I'm erasing the others, sorry for the trouble).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you need to reshape data (maybe it is done within the model while training, can't say without the code). Try something like this:

```
print(model.predict(X_test[39].reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1),verbose=2))
```